# No network connectivity with virtio drivers under WinXP guest (libvirt/Qemu on Linux host)

Tags: networking, windows, virtio

I've been using `libvirt` for a couple of years now and it's worked a treat so far. Just until recently (probably after a few system updates on my Manjaro Linux host): none of my Windows (XP) guests have network connectivity with virtio drivers anymore. Instead I must switch to `rtl8139`, then network connectivity works fine. As a corollary, I have to wait a very long time in my Windows guests until I can finally check the network adapters settings; otherwise no network icon appears nor does the `Network connections` window when I right click on `Network Favourites` and select `Properties`. The wait period occurs regardless of whether I set IP addresses manually to the interfaces or use DHCP.

I started to notice this issue while booting my old Windows XP virtual machine. It was virtio drivers version **0.1.106** (or close) installed back then. So I upgraded the `virtio` network drivers first, like I did in the past. Something odd though: updating the driver took forever and I had to forcibly power off the VM and restart it again. I also uninstalled the drivers completely after I switched to `rtl8139` then re-installed them again (using Windows [Device Manager Non Present Devices](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184583.aspx) trick). No change.

I have tried `virtio` drivers from the [Fedora project](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Windows_Virtio_Drivers#Direct_download) version **0.1.135** (latest) and **0.1.126** (stable). No difference. The previous drivers, which used to work back then where from 2013. Needless to say they don't now either. It looks like only my Windows guests are affected. None of my old Linux guests exhibit that glitch as they all receive an IP address from my host's `dnsmasq` daemon.

Does anyone have an idea?

(N.B.: The event log doesn't reveal nothing about anything going wrong. That said it's no surprise to me.)

Comment: Is it possible that the virtio drivers simply no longer support XP?

Comment: @roaima There's a dedicated folder for XP\x86 on the `virtio` drivers ISO image so I guess, no, support isn't dropped yet.

Answer (score 0):

You may be writing about the problem [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1530994.html). This is a bug in `qemu 2.8.`
As a workaround set driver to `qemu` (instead of `vhost`) `xml` file (`virsh` edit [VmName]) [here] - it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That will [hopefully] help. I'll try this and report. BTW I get an SSL error *SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_READ* with the first link, dunno why.